# Deleting multiple pointers with single delete operator

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

For deleting and an array of element we use `delete[]`.
Is it possible to delete the pointers the way I am doing below?

```
ClassA* object = new ClassA();
ClassA* pointer1 = object;

ClassA* object2 = new ClassA();
ClassA* pointer2 = object2;

delete pointer1,pointer2;
```

Why its not possible to use delete this way?

**[Edit]**

Can I put it like, what are the drawbacks due to which the above delete has not been implemented?

Comment: Because there is no syntax for it. Because Bjarne didn't put it in. It's not a real question, unless you can find someone on the ANSI or ISO committee who was present when and if it was ever considered.

Comment: Antoine de Saint-Exupery once wrote *In anything at all, perfection is finally attained not when there is no longer anything to add, but when there is no longer anything to take away.* Likewise, a programming language is not made better by including anything and everything; it is just made more complex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible, because there is no provision for it in the C++ language definition. I'm not sure there is any "good" answer to why the language doesn't support a list of items for `delete`, except for the fact that it's simpler to not do that.

You need to write one `delete` for each variable. Of course, if you have many `pointerX`, then you probably should be using an array instead, and use a loop to delete the objects.

Edit: Of course, if you are calling `delete` in many places in your code, you are probably doing something wrong - or at least, you are not following the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principles very well. It's of course necessary to learn/understand dynamic allocation to have full understanding of the language, but you should really avoid calling both `new` and `delete` in your own code - let someone else sort that out (or write classes that do "the right thing")

Answer (score 1):

It is not working this way. delete is a command for a single pointer. You can put the pointers in a structure (e.g. array) or a container (e.g. using a vector container class) and delete for each one of them by iterating the structure/container.

Comment: @john: I think Nick is referring to a container or array, rather than a `struct`.

Comment: You can either use a loop with an index increasing to get the index each time, or, if it is about a container, to use an iterator object.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You are right (updated the answer), but this is on his choice on what to use, structures or container classes.

Comment: In C++11 you can write your own variadic "deletes" function. Even simpler is: `for (auto &p : {pointer1,pointer2}) { delete p; }`.